# how to write a udf in java for pig to parse xml file

Tags: java, apache-pig

I am writing a java udf for pig to parse an xml file. I have written a basic eval function to print the record. Can i use any of the parsers DOM, SAX or Stax? the udf is applied on each record in the xml file. I have a DOM parser code to extract the values and key. 
xml syntax:

```
<record>
<field name= "Name" key= "8421">asdf</field>
<field name= "qwer" key="9090">dfgh</field>
</record>
```